# How can I extract a number above 999 with a the comma using regu

Tags: regex, vb.net

What's the pattern for extracting a number over 1000 with a comma. I've tried a lot of different patterns but the pattern I'm using only extracts the first number before the comma and not the whole number with comma. So what pattern can I use to extract any number above 999 with the comma included.

Here's my pattern: "(\d*,)\d*"

Working pattern for digits under 1000:

```
Dim rgxPostsCount As New Regex("class=[""]counts_media[""]>\d*")
Dim mchPostsCount As Match = rgxPostsCount.Match(strData)
If mchPostsCount.Success Then
Dim strPostsCount As String = mchPostsCount.Value.Substring(21, mchPostsCount.Length - 21)
MessageBox.Show(strPostsCount)
```

Non working pattern for digits over 999: I would like to keep the comma.
    If strPostsCount > 999 Then
     rgxPostsCount = New Regex("class=[""]counts_media[""]>(\d*,)\d*")
     chPostsCount = rgxPostsCount.Match(strData)
     MessageBox.Show(mchPostsCount.Value)
    End If

Comment: post some examples for match and unmatch strings.

Answer (score 0):

As an ERE,

```
[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})+
```

Some examples:

```
$ for n in \
444444,000,000 1,000,000 11,000,000 11,000,00 11,000,000 \
11,000,000 1,000 999 9,99 10,000; do \
  echo $n '->' $(echo $n | grep -E -o  -w '[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})+$' || echo nope); \
done
444444,000,000 -> nope
1,000,000 -> 1,000,000
11,000,000 -> 11,000,000
11,000,00 -> nope
11,000,000 -> 11,000,000
11,000,000 -> 11,000,000
1,000 -> 1,000
999 -> nope
9,99 -> nope
10,000 -> 10,000
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches every number >= 1000:

```
0*[1-9][\d]{3,}(?:[,.]\d+)?
```

---

If you only want to match numbers with comma:

```
0*[1-9][\d]{3,},\d+
```